# how publish joint velocity command?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS MELODIC, GAZEBO 9
Hi, i'm working to set up a quadcopter simulation within gazebo. I have created the model and added 4 transmission element ( one for each motor ) and to control them i use the ros_control plugins. Thus, i have created a file.yaml in which i specify my controllers:

```
joint_motor_controller:
    type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController
    joints: 
        - joint_front_right_prop
        - joint_front_left_prop
        - joint_back_left_prop
        - joint_back_right_prop
    gains:
        joint_front_right_prop: {p: 10000, i: 1, d: 1000}
        joint_front_left_prop: {p: 10000, i: 1, d: 1000}
        joint_back_left_prop: {p: 10000, i: 1, d: 1000}
        joint_back_right_prop: {p: 10000, i: 1, d: 1000}
```

the problem arise when i try to publish from a ros node the velocity. the publisher objects is :

```
ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Float64MultiArray("/drone/joint_motor_controller/command",4);
```

but when i run the node i get the node i get the following error in gazebo:

```
ERROR: dimension of command ( #) does not match number of joint (4).
```

any help??? thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374319/how-publish-joint-velocity-command?/) by [FedeBO](https://answers.ros.org/users/72204/fedebo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The type of data you are publishing is a [Float64 array](http://docs.ros.org/en/jade/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Float64MultiArray.html) but you are only sending a single value "4". Try publishing an array (values in square brackets). So maybe [4] instead of 4 if you are trying to send a single value

---

Originally posted by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) with karma: 459 on 2021-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FedeBO](https://answers.ros.org/users/72204/fedebo/) on 2021-03-22**:
Thanks for your answer, i have already fix it on my own. I was publishing a float64array without specifing the dimension. I simply use the resize() method :)))